# Combining RGB colours of pictures into one picture: Python, Cimpl

Tags: python, rgb

The problem is to combine three RGB pictures to make an original picture. I need to take as an input three filtered pictures in RGB of the same picture. One red, one green, and one blue. I've tried to take every pixel in the image and add it to a tuple, which stores values of it.

```
from Cimpl import *

red_image = load_image("red_image.jpg")
blue_image = load_image("blue_image.jpg")
green_image = load_image("green_image.jpg")

new_image = copy(red_image)

for pixel in new_image:

    x, y, (r, g, b) = pixel

for bluePixel in blue_image:
    xBlue, yBlue, (rBlue, gBlue, bBlue) = bluePixel
    new_colour = create_color(r+rBlue,g+gBlue,b+bBlue)
    set_color (new_image, x, y, new_colour)


for greenPixel in green_image:
    xGreen, yGreen, (rGreen, gGreen, bGreen) = greenPixel
    new_colour = create_color(r+rGreen,g+gGreen,b+bGreen)
    set_color (new_image, x, y, new_colour)    

show(red_image)
show(new_image)
```

I seem to get the same picture back again and not the "combined image" of red, blue and green filters( red_image.jpg because I use that as "new_image")

Answer (score 0):

Let's make things clear, you have 3 images, each of them has 1 channel and you want to combine them into 1 3 channels image? If I'm right then try this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

red = cv2.imread('red.jpg')
green = cv2.imread('green.jpg')
blue = cv2.imread('blue.jpg')

image = np.dstack((blue, green, red)) # combine them, I'm not sure should I use red or blue first here though

cv2.imwrite('image.jpg')  # save it

cv2.imshow('img', image)  # show it
cv2.waitKey()
```

Note that opencv use BGR instead of RGB.

If you don't have `cv2` and `numpy` yet.

```
pip install numpy
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: I think it's not really necessary to use pip3. If `python` command(not `python3`) show a 3.7

Comment: Yes, should've made the question more concise. Also, is there a way of doing it with no libraries?

Comment: I need to know what's in `Cimpl` in case you don't want to use external libraries, but honestly it's way better to use than not. Python is really slow by itself alone and these libraries(`numpy` and `opencv`) are the most standard python libraries out there

Comment: Show me the `Cimpl`

Comment: Use cv2.merge() in place of np.dstack. That way numpy is not needed.

Comment: I have figured out a way to do it without using libraries that you mentioned. Thanks anyway. It was just a matter of adding the pixels of each rgb image together